# How to parse hostname in URI.js to remove 'www.'?

Tags: javascript, parsing, url, uri, uri.js

I want [to use URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) to parse a URL to get the hostname without the 'www.'.

```
const hostname = URI('http//www.example.com').hostname()
// -> Produces: 'www.example.com'
// Instead, I want: 'example.com'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
const hostname = URI('http//www.example.com').domain()
```

More details on https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#accessors-domain